# FreeDiameter ULA/ULR messages

Tags: free-diameter

I try to connect my entity (as MME) with HSS by s6a interface.
Connection (CER / CEA) is successful:

[there is report and configuration file for test_app in my cloud](https://yadi.sk/i/xhBhS2VD3Jy2Ra)

however after that I cannot obtain correct ULA:
[ULA screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqyAo.png)

I use test_app.fdx. Maybe it is impossible to use this extension for this aim?

If yes, how can I achieve correct results?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

ULA Screenshot have Failed AVP {Auth-Session-State} which is mandatory AVP in ULR.

Can you try uncommenting below line in you configuration?

## auth-session-state = 0;

Comment: Actually, I add this line by myself. There is no property auth-session-state in original configuration and hence this one does not influence solution. To sum up, it was my attempt and it was unseccessful action.

Answer (score 0):

Diameter error code 5005 means the mandatory IE is missing.
So check the ULR message sent from the tool and match with the 3gpp specs for mandatory AVP that is missing.

Comment: This is considered a comment I suggest you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask